# How os.File Read method modifies the bytes of slice in golang?

Tags: go

For example in below, `Data` is not going to change in `main` block -

```
import "fmt"

func main(){
    Data := make([]byte,3)
    Modify(Data)
    fmt.Println(Data) //output is [0,0,0]
}

func Modify(data []byte){
    data = []byte{1,2,3}
}
```

But while reading a file and storing bytes to a slice `b`, the read method can change the bytes in `b` -
[As Written Here](https://pkg.go.dev/os#File.Read)

```
func (f *File) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error)
```

How does `Read` Method can modify caller's `b`?

Comment: `For example in below, Data is not going to change in main block` You're not changing values in the slice, you create an entirely new slice. Two different things.

Comment: @tkausl yes true. but the same should have happened with file read method, but somehow it can change the `b` in main block.

Comment: `but the same should have happened with file read` no.

Comment: @tkausl wow! please clarify it how. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Read` can modify `b` because you pass a slice with nonzero length. `Read` sets the bytes into `b` up to length... **it does not set `b` slice**. Your own function `Modify` sets the slice that is a local copy. If you assign by index up to slice length, `Modify` also has modifying behaviour.

```
func Modify(data []byte) {
    for i := 0; i < len(data); i++ {
        data[i] = i
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg! I can modify the data without doing `func Modify(data *[]byte)`. that means even though `Modify` has its own copy but those addresses of elements inside are same. Thank you again.